# CakePHP 3.0 echo content of css file in template

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp, html-email

I have css stylesheet for all e-mail templates which is placed in the

```
/webroot/css/email-layout.css
```

I trying to display css inline in templates using the:

```
<style type="text/css">
        <?php echo $this->Html->css(array('email-layout.css')); ?>
</style>
```

But after receiving the email is still displayed like link, not inline.

How can i solve it please?

Many thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your style is an internet link (external file)? You need to output this css file as internal file when generating e-mail. For example:

```
<style>
<?php echo file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/css/email-layout.css'); ?>
</style>
```

Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

`<?php echo $this->Html->css(array('email-layout.css')); ?>`

will output

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/email-layout.css" />`

But if you want to get the file content, use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function

```
<style type="text/css">
    <?php echo file_get_contents(WWW_ROOT . 'css' . DS . 'email-layout.css'); ?>
</style>
```

`WWW_ROOT` : Full path to the webroot.